# C program produces weird output

Tags: c, arrays, unix, memory, struct

During my process of Learning C I decided to create a ***struct*** that gives me the size of fish I provide in it, my question is why when I write this small piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct fish
    {
        char catfish[9]; //reserve memory for 9 chars
        char goldfish[10]; //reserve memory for 10 chars
        char mackrel;
        char oldfish;
    };

int main()
{
    struct fish typeof_fish;

    strcpy(typeof_fish.catfish, "Big Fish\n");
    strcpy(typeof_fish.goldfish, "Small Fish\n");
    printf("%s\n", typeof_fish.catfish);

    return 0;


}
```

the output produces "Big Fish Small Fish"
[Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ZEb.png)

yet when I rewrite the top piece of code and change char ***catfish[9]***; to char ***catfish[10]***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct fish
    {
        char catfish[10]; //reserve memory for 10 chars
        char goldfish[10]; //reserve memory for 10 chars
        char mackrel;
        char oldfish;
    };

int main()
{
    struct fish typeof_fish;

    strcpy(typeof_fish.catfish, "Big Fish\n");
    strcpy(typeof_fish.goldfish, "Small Fish\n");
    printf("%s\n", typeof_fish.catfish);

    return 0;


}
```

it produces "Big Fish" [output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXZko.png)

thank you in advance for an answer on this puzzling bug

Comment: You're overrunning your arrays. `"Small Fish\n"`, for example, occupies **12** chars. It isn't going to fit in a 10 char array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't leaving enough room for a null terminator in `catfish[9]` when you strcpy `"Big Fish\n"`. That string is 9 characters long, which means you need a size-10 buffer to store the null-terminator.

If a string misses the null terminator the output has undefined behaviour since the program has no way to know where the string ends.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

When you perform the first copy, `strcpy()` copies in total 10 bytes (9 from the string itself plus the terminator). As you have allocated only 9 bytes in `catfish`, the terminator goes into the first byte of `goldfish`, which then gets overwritten when you copy the second string. Hence, when you do a `printf()` of `catfish`, it doesn't stop at the end of `catfish` but keeps printing until it finds the terminator at the end of `goldfish`.

In the second case you add enough space for the terminator not to be overwritten so when you print it will just print the contents of `catfish` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation